# Why ghc give me a parse error when I wish to simply print out a value?

Tags: parsing, haskell, compilation, ghc

I've got a haskell file:

```
main = putStrLn "hello world"
let a=1
show a
```

and ghc says:

```
main.hs:3:1:                                                                                                                            
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

First, if you want to sequence expressions in `IO` you need to place them in a `do` block. Second, you need to use indentation (spaces only, no tabs!) to delimit the do block, like so:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "hello world"
   let a=1
   show a
```

Finally, `show a` will return a string, but you want an IO action that *prints* a string, so it should be `putStrLn (show a)`, or you can use `print a` as the print function is the composition of `show`ing (turning into a string) and then printing out to the console.